# System.Data.SQLite equivalent for SqlDbType.Structured?

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

On the current project I'm working on, I often have a collection of up to a 1000 (`int` or `string`) values, I want to match in a select statement (using the IN operator). The project supports both SQL Server and SQLite.

In SQL Server the solution is pretty easy.
I created 2 new types:

```
CREATE TYPE IntegerList AS TABLE(IntValue INT NOT NULL);
CREATE TYPE StringList AS TABLE(StrValue VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL);
```

In my C# code I do as follows:

```
using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
  command.CommandText = someComplexSelectStatment + " AND T.Value IN (SELECT StrValue FROM @Values)";
  SqlParameter parameter = command.CreateParameter() as SqlParameter;
  parameter.ParameterName = "@Values";
  parameter.Value = data;
  parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
  parameter.TypeName = "dbo.StringList";
  command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
  // use an IDataReader to retrieve the results
}
```

Where data is a `DataTable` of a `DbDataReader`. I've written my own generic `DbDataReader`, which is able to use an `IEnumerable<T>` as source.

Is there any equivalent to do this in SQLite ? The only solution I see (apart from inserting the data into a temporary table), would be to create a huge string like: `... AND T.Value IN ('Value1','Value2','Value3',...)`. This does not seem a very performant solution to me.

I can not perform the select statement without the IN operator (and filter the result on the collection) as the result would contain too many results (up to a million records).

Marc

Comment: There's nothing like that in sqlite. How about using separate tables for those values, with the "main" table having one-to-many relationship to them?

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: The is no one-to-many relationship. If I would perform the select without the IN operator, I would have as many different `T.Value` values as I would have resulting rows.